# ZFS on Linux: cannot destroy snapshot, dataset is busy

Tags: linux, centos, zfs, storage

I'm trying to delete a bunch of old ZFS snapshots but I get errors saying that the datasets are busy:

```
[root@pool-01 ~]# zfs list -t snapshot -o name -S creation | grep ^pool/nfs/public/mydir | xargs -n 1 zfs destroy -vr
will destroy pool/nfs/public/mydir@autosnap_2019-02-24_03:13:17_hourly
will reclaim 408M
cannot destroy snapshot pool/nfs/public/mydir@autosnap_2019-02-24_03:13:17_hourly: dataset is busy
will destroy pool/nfs/public/mydir@autosnap_2019-02-24_02:13:17_hourly
will reclaim 409M
 cannot destroy snapshot pool/nfs/public/mydir@autosnap_2019-02-24_02:13:17_hourly: dataset is busy
will destroy pool/nfs/public/mydir@autosnap_2019-02-24_01:13:18_hourly will reclaim 394M
```

Running `lsof` shows no processes accessing these snapshots:

```
[root@pool-01 ~]# lsof | grep pool/nfs/public/mydir
```

There also appears to be no holds on any of the snapshots:

```
[root@pool-01 ~]# zfs holds pool/nfs/public/mydir@autosnap_2019-02-24_03:13:17_hourly
NAME                                                              TAG  TIMESTAMP
```

Is there anything else I should look out for? Anything else I can do besides a reoot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be unintended behavior on ZoL, I left the ZFS box alone for a few days and finally gave up and rebooted the said box, and I was able to destroy those snapshots after reboot.

Answer (score 3):

Originally, I used the following method to stop a busy dataset to enable me to export this dataset for a pool rebuild. I use a ZFS dataset for my `/home` directory and I was unable to find the process which kept it busy. Here's my solution which should work for you too, when you cannot find the process using your dataset:

1. On all dataset(s) you wish to export (but had trouble exporting) set:

   ```
   zfs set canmount=noauto dataset1
   zfs set canmount=noauto dataset2
   ...
   # and so on where you substitute your datasets' names for dataset1, dataset2, ...
   ```

   Setting `canmount=noauto` ensures that the dataset will not mount on reboot
2. Make a user account (or use the root account) which doesn't use the dataset for `/home` etc... Give this account sudo privileges.
3. Reboot and log into the above account, i.e. the account you just created in step 2. This account should boot up without mounting the datasets you modified in step 1 and therefore, deny those datasets to any daemons/programs.
4. Since the datasets are now not busy, you can now destroy them and/or their snapshots.
5. Be sure to:

   ```
   zfs set canmount=on dataset1
   zfs set canmount=on dataset2
   ...
   ```

   to any datasets that you want to mount on boot. This is the zfs default.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that my snapshots were indeed busy for some reason - they all were shown in the output of

```
mount
```

So I did something reckless and just cast

```
sudo umount /.zfs/snapshot/*
```

Against all expectations, nothing bad seems to have happened. And then my `sudo zfs destroy` worked.

Comment: Indeed. I had the visibility of snapshots for some datasets enabled  "zfs set snapdir=visible zfs/appdata/my_dataset" which kept them mounted and busy for zfs operations.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the "zfs-way",
This fixes it for me and I assume it's considered more correct/clean:

```bash
#Use a variable so we need less hard-coding:
THE_DATA_SET=pool/nfs/public/mydir

#Make mounting impossible for a while (this also umounts it):
zfs canmount=off $THE_DATA_SET

#Find all snapshots and destroy them:
#("tail -n +2" is needed to remove the header in the "zfs list" output)
zfs list $THE_DATA_SET -t snapshot -o name | tail -n +2  | xargs -n 1 zfs destroy

#Make mounting possible again and do it:
zfs canmount=on $THE_DATA_SET
zfs mount $THE_DATA_SET

#And now we longer need the variable:
unset THE_DATA_SET
```

Comment: I you want to be really safe: Put a `echo` in front of `zfs destroy` to see what would we be destroyed. (And if you are happy run it again without the `echo`)